# Default radio button select value angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am working on angular material 2 radio button following this documentation:https://material.angular.io/components/component/radio.

The problem that I am facing is to have the radio button a default selected value of `No`. If you see in the plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/jdRxVLdSfFqR4XOdpyUN?p=preview you will find that none of the options are selected. I would want the default value to be `No` when the page loads.

Answer (score 24):

A lot of the plunkrs don't seem to work for me anymore. There's a modified stackblitz here:

[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jh9mpq?file=app%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html)

As mentioned we can either set the ngModel and the variable:

```
[(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason"
```

and in the 'ts' file:

```
  favoriteSeason: string = 'Winter';
```

Or we can set the checked:

```
[checked]="season === 'Winter'"
```

Another little gotcha I've discovered recently is that if you mistakenly give mat-checkbox incorrect (duplicate IDs), then it does not work - you cannot check anything. Ensure your IDs are unique.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `checked`, like so:

```
[checked]="data.value ==='false'"
```

notice that we are checking using string `'false'`, instead of `false`, as your value has the string with value `false`.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/aYwGK7yhT0LHFhfXjl6m?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 9):

```
<mat-radio-button [checked]="true"</mat-radio-button>
```

Comment: It is recommended to add some descriptions for the answer you've posted,

Comment: The question dates from 1,5 years ago, and several other answers have already mentioned the use of `[checked]` and they are not limited to a static value, but set the value depending on the user's actual data. This answer does not add anything useful, and certainly not when it has no description.

Comment: or just plain `checked` without any Angular related stuff

Comment: i dont speak english

Answer (score 6):

I love the reactive approach when working with material radio buttons. Below is an example of how to check for true and false with your database for a specific formControlName

**Component within the Dialog Box**

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="trueClient">
                <mat-radio-button class="material-radio" value="true" [checked]="data.trueClient === 'true'">True Client</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button class="material-radio" value="false" [checked]="data.lostLead === 'false'">Lost Lead</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
```

If this is an update form, make sure to set the values in your form builder. Example below:

**.ts file for the component within the dialog box.**

```
this.viewClient.setValue({
      trueClient: this.data.trueClient
    });
```

In this case i am opening the data within a dialog box. So the data is coming from the below:
component.ts prior that opens the dialog box. Just a reference so that you know where i got the data variable from above to set the values.

Component used to open the dialog box. Reference to [Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) in Materials docs for more info on how to setup.

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ClientNotesComponent, {
        height: '600px',
        width: '800px',
        data: {trueClient: trueClient}
    });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it with `[checked]` attribute.
See this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nkz4FTWWoGmVthhGq63p?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

there is another option which is you can use `[(ngModel)]` to initialize the `md-radio-group` with your component.

plunker [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jp2onftG2kaI30C5Wfcy?p=preview).

Comment: Be aware that if using `[(ngModel)]`, you can no longer use the `[checked]` property.  For example, if you explicitly set `[checked]` to `false`, but the component variable that is bound to the `mat-radio-group` has a value that is equal to the value of this `mat-radio-button`, the radio button will indeed remain checked

Answer (score 2):

HTML file

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" [(ngModel)]="formValues['type']">
    <mat-radio-button value="individual">Individual</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="business">Business</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Ts file

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.formValues['type'] = "business";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the selection issue has been resolved by replacing the `name="howLong"` attribute with `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`. 
Point to be noted, the selelction was working for `A day or less than a day`. But it was not working for `More than a day`

Non working version:

```
   <mat-radio-group
        [(ngModel)]="howLong"
        name="howLong"
        (change)="resetTime()">
        <mat-radio-button class="ignore" value="MoreThanADay">
            More than a day
        </mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="ADayOrLessThanADay">A day or less than a day</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

Working version:

```
   <mat-radio-group
        [(ngModel)]="howLong"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        (change)="resetTime()">
        <mat-radio-button class="ignore" value="MoreThanADay">
            More than a day
        </mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="ADayOrLessThanADay">A day or less than a day</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass a string or boolean to your mat-radio-group using [(ngModel)],
you can set a default value for your [(ngModel)] in the TS file. 
like this: [HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsSgK.png)

[Ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3ZhN.png)

Comment: Try to avoid image urls with source code. It's better to add your source code as codeblock directly to your question/answer. This will increases the readability and quality. Take a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and welcome to SO.